# return True if the strings "mat" and "jet" appear the same number of times in the given string,

Tags: python, string

String s with last element (in this code 'long' ) is not able to go to the elif condition... How to make it right?

The code I used:

```
def check_occurence(string):  
    count=0 
    count1=0
    s=""
    for i in string:
        if i != " ":
             s=s+i
        elif i == " ":
            if s == 'jet' or s == 'Jet':
                count=count+1
            elif (s=='mat' or s=='Mat'):
                count1=count1+1
            s=""
    if count == count1: 
        return True 
    else: 
        return False      

string="Jet on the Mat but mat is too long"  
print(check_occurence(string))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648), and provide a [mre]. "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site because SO isn't a free online coding service. You have to _make an honest attempt_, and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Initial value of `s` is a **space** (`" "`). By appending characters to the space one never get `jet` or `Jet` or whatever string which doesn't start with space. Why don't initialize `s` with an empty string (`""`)?

Comment: Tsyvarev thanks

Comment: You are trying to tokenize `string` yourself by building `s` character by character; Python is a high-level language that offers the `str.split()` method (try `for word in "Jet on the Mat but mat is too long".split()`)

Comment: I hopr my answer helped you solve the question

Comment: If my answer resolved your problem I invite you to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count method, that returns the number of times a string appears in another string
Like this:

```
def check_occurence(str):
    return (str.count('jet')+str.count('Jet'))==(str.count('mat')+str.count('Mat'))
```

You just add the number of times the string appear with and without the first letter uppercase and return their equality.